# VBA: Using an And Statement within an If Else Loop

Tags: vba, excel

For all cells in column K (in row 5 down to the last row) that have a value of 0 in column G on the same row, and value in column I on the same row, the Macro should auto-fill the word "Paid".

For all other situations the Macro should auto-fill the phrase "Paid Not Yet Processed".  My code is below but I keep getting an error message at the start of the If statement.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks

```
Sub Amount()

Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 5 To Lastrow
If ActiveSheet.Range("I" & i).Value <> " " And _
ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i).Value = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("K" & i).Value = "Paid"
Else
    ActiveSheet.Range("K" & i).Value = "Processed Not Yet Paid"
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What error message do you keep getting at the start of the `If` statement?

Comment: Do you have any error values in column I or column G?

Comment: The error message says "Run-time error '13':  Type mismatch".  A few of the columns have #N/A values returned from a V-Lookup buyt I do not believe these should throw off the Macro, other than that, no errors

Comment: You can't compare a `#N/A` error value to a string - it generates a type mismatch error

Comment: How do you suggest I solve this issue? incorporate code into my Macro that gets rid of the #N/As first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for errors before comparing against strings, etc:

```
Sub Amount()        
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 5 To Lastrow
            If IsError(.Range("I" & i).Value) Or IsError(.Range("G" & i).Value) Then
                .Range("K" & i).Value = "Processed Not Yet Paid"
            ElseIf .Range("I" & i).Value <> " " And _
                   .Range("G" & i).Value = 0 Then
                .Range("K" & i).Value = "Paid"
            Else
                .Range("K" & i).Value = "Processed Not Yet Paid"
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Note: The test for `<> " "` will only be `False` if the cell contains a single space.  So an Empty cell will return `True` for that test.  I'm not sure whether that is what you intended.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.  This largly worked but I realized my problem iwth it comes earlier in my code. I used this equation to fill in a blank but, after using an If statement, I realized there is no blank:  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B:B,Sheet1!$D:$M,4,0)," ")        Is there a better way to go about this in Column I?

Comment: The table that the information is being pulled from has a the number that matches up with my reference, it's just that the column requesting to be returned has nothing in it for some of them.  I thought the IfError statement would return a blank for those but it hasn't.

Comment: @oryan5000 If a `VLOOKUP` returns an empty string, that is not classed as an error, so `IFERROR` won't set your cell to be a string containing a single space.  But I think you can get around that in the VBA by simply changing `ElseIf .Range("I" & i).Value <> " " And _` to be `ElseIf Trim(.Range("I" & i).Value) <> "" And _` which will treat a `" "` and a `""` as the same thing.

Comment: @oryan5000 Oh - Until I read the comments on the other answer, I hadn't even noticed that your `VLOOKUP` would always be returning an error.

Answer (score 0):

Error catching may be confusing for newer users. Here's one other approach that uses a function non-vba Excel users are likely familiar with -- **CountIf**. This will defend against any error values/text/#NA/DiV/0?OH/NO!. Essentially a true test of some value true or something else.

OP - Note that you have a " " in your code (includes a space), which I'm guessing might need to be "" if you mean blank.

```
Sub Amount()
Dim WS As Worksheet     'Just a suggestion to keep more dynamic
Set WS = ActiveSheet    'Just a suggestion to keep more dynamic

Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long
Lastrow = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 5 To Lastrow
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(WS.Range("I" & i), " ") = 0 And _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(WS.Range("G" & i), 0) = 1 Then
    WS.Range("K" & i).Value = "Paid"
Else
    WS.Range("K" & i).Value = "Processed Not Yet Paid"
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  As I posted in response to the other answer, my problem comes earlier because there is not a true space where there is supposed to be one.  I have this equation in Column I but there is not a space in the blank cells.  What would you suggest doing differently?      =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B:B,Sheet1!$D:$M,4,0)," ")           The table that the information is being pulled from has a the number that matches up with my reference, it's just that the column requesting to be returned has nothing in it for some.  Is there a way you'd alter the IfError statement given this information?

Comment: Your vlookup formula is messed up. The first argument needs to be a single value, not an entire column (B:B). Maybe something like =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet1!$D:$M,4,0),"")

Comment: Thank you, the problem was resolved through the use of an IfError netted within an If Statement